# LyX cannot transform figures into Sumatra?

Tags: lyx, sumatrapdf

I am using LyX and Sumatra PDF. I insert a figure in my LyX but when I click "View PDF (PdfLaTeX)", an error jumps out, it says:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode - synctex=1 "(my file name).tex"
```

What's my problem? Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is no error message, this is just the call which is used to create the PDF file from your LyX/LaTeX file to view it afterwards.

Comment: I suggest posting a minimal example: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample